# I want to make the tiles they make in windows 8

Tags: asp.net, css

how can i make the tiles that is in windows 8 and then use it in my website that is not yet hosted?'
All searches ive done only takes me to how to make a tile on a windows 8 pc and thats not what i want to do
Any advice or help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a few links you can hit to get the styles to do it in a website:
http://www.noupe.com/css/metro-ui-css-own-tiled-website-71225.html